# Can we find the user id/name in PingAccess logs?

Tags: single-sign-on, pingaccess

Can we find the user id/name in PingAccess logs ? which is passing to the application as a value for attribute which mapped in PingAcess configuration ?

Thanks in advance!
Ping

Answer (score 2):

The PingAccess log file "pingaccess_engine_audit.log" will have the userId that is contained in the PA_Token when an authenticated user requests access to a resource. The "pingaccess.log" will contain other identity attributes you have configured to be present in that token as well.